# Using the Minkowski Bound

Tags: number-theory, ideals

[image]

Can someone please explain why the second sentence in this example is true.

Comment: The Minkowski bound gives you a bound on the norm of an ideal in the ring of integers of $K$ and since this is less than $3$ and $\operatorname{Cl}_K$ is generated by the classes of prime ideals, you only need to check primes lying over $2$.

Comment: Do you mean the sentence beginning with the word “Here”?